# Correct usage of "If I were"

Tags: conditional-constructions, subjunctives

Which of the following sentences are correct?

1. If I was him, I'd buy a car later when I have money.
2. If I was him, I'd buy a car later when I had money.
3. If I was in her place, I'd ask the kids if they want another animal.
4. If I was in her place, I'd ask the kids if they wanted another animal.

I think the second and the fourth ones are correct. But I'm not sure if the others are wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In formal use all of these require *were* for the condition (*IF*) clause, because they are all "counterfactual", conditions "contrary to fact": you are **not** him, you are **not** in her place.

You have correctly employed "I'd" (= *I would*) as counterfactuals in the consequence (*THEN*) clauses.

The tense in a subordinate clause is not necessarily determined by the tense of a main clause, so the  "want" and "have" clauses may take either the present or the past form: depending on circumstances, the "facts" (having money later and wanting another animal) may be regarded as either doubtful or certain.

But in colloquial use all are acceptable.

Comment: +1. Also, interesting NGram http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If+I+were+you%2C+If+I+was+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @Matt Ayup. We don' need no stinkin subjunctive.

Comment: @Matt: I think the "death of the subjunctive" is more marked than your NGram would suggest. Pupils probably still get *"If I **were** you"* drummed into them at school, so when they're *writing* (not *speaking*) they still tend to follow the outdated rule more than their natural inclinations. But change it just slightly, to [if it **were/was** me](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=If+it+were+me%2CIf+it+was+me&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), and we find the subjunctive already in "second place" - even in print.

Comment: @Matt Well, I did [this on Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=iwant%2CI+wanna&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ciwant%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20wanna%3B%2Cc0) and given **that** result, I wouldn't trust the relation between popularity and correctness. After all, if we go by majority decision, we have a gazillion flies who like to eat poo...